# Substracting timedelta in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe with two columns (date and days).

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[2020-01-31, 2020-01-21, 2020-01-11], 'days':[1, 2, 3]})
```

I want to have a third column `(date_2)` for which to substract the number of days from the date. Therefore, `date_2` would be `[2020-01-30, 2020-01-19, 2020-01-8]`.

I know `timedelta(days = i)` but I cannot give it the content of `df['days']` as `i` in pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with `unit=d` and subtract

```
>>pd.to_datetime(df['date'])-pd.to_timedelta(df['days'],unit='d')

0   2020-01-30
1   2020-01-19
2   2020-01-08
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for datetimes and subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with timedeltas created by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).sub(pd.to_timedelta(df['days'], unit='d'))
print (df)
         date  days        new
0  2020-01-31     1 2020-01-30
1  2020-01-21     2 2020-01-19
2  2020-01-11     3 2020-01-08
```